# Unable to append data to array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am retrieving a record set from a database.
Then using a **for** statement I am trying to construct my data to match a 3rd party API.

But I get this error and can't figure it out:

> "errorType": "TypeError",   "errorMessage": "list indices must be
>   integers, not str"
>   "messages['english']['merge_vars']['vars'].append({"

Below is my code:

```
cursor = connect_to_database()

records = get_records(cursor)

template = dict()

messages = dict()

template['english'] = "SOME_TEMPLATE reminder-to-user-english"

messages['english'] = {
    'subject': "Reminder (#*|code|*)",
    'from_email': 'mail@mail.com',
    'from_name': 'Notifier',
    'to': [],
    'merge_vars': [],
    'track_opens': True,
    'track_clicks': True,
    'important': True
}

for record in records:

    record = dict(record)

    if record['lang'] == 'english':

        messages['english']['to'].append({
            'email': record['email'],
            'type': 'to'
        })

        messages['english']['merge_vars'].append({
            'rcpt': record['email']
        })

        for (key, value) in record.iteritems():

            messages['english']['merge_vars']['vars'].append({
                'name': key,
                'content': value
            })

    else:

        template['other'] = "SOME_TEMPLATE reminder-to-user-other"

close_database_connection()

return messages
```

The goal is to get something like this below:

```
messages = {
 'subject': "...",
 'from_email': "...",
 'from_name': "...",
 'to': [
   {
     'email': '...',
     'type': 'to',
   },
   {
     'email': '...',
     'type': 'to',
   }
 ],
 'merge_vars': [
  {
    'rcpt': '...',
    'vars': [
      {
       'content': '...',
       'name': '...'
      },
      {
       'content': '...',
       'name': '...'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'rcpt': '...',
    'vars': [
      {
       'content': '...',
       'name': '...'
      },
      {
       'content': '...',
       'name': '...'
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please also shared the content of `records`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems to indicate that `messages['english']['merge_vars']` is a list, since you initialize it as such:

```
messages['english'] = {
    ...
    'merge_vars': [],
    ...
}
```

And call `append` on it:

```
messages['english']['merge_vars'].append({
    'rcpt': record['email']
})
```

However later, you treat it as a dictionary when you call:

```
messages['english']['merge_vars']['vars']
```

It seems what you want is something more like:

```
vars = [{'name': key, 'content': value} for key, value in record.iteritems()]
messages['english']['merge_vars'].append({
    'rcpt': record['email'],
    'vars': vars,
})
```

Then, the `for` loop is unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, but this gives me a "list index out of range" error on the same line.

Comment: I think I see now what you wanted. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is saying is that you are trying to access an array element with the help of string not index (int).

I believe your mistake is in this line:

```
messages['english']['merge_vars']['vars'].append({..})
```

You declared `merge_vars` as array like so:

```
'merge_vars': []
```

So, you either make it `dict` like this:

```
'merge_vars': {}
```

Or, use it as array:

```
messages['english']['merge_vars'].append({..})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your issues, as the Error Message is saying, is here:  `messages['english']['merge_vars']['vars'].append({'name': key,'content': value})`

The item `messages['english']['merge_vars']` is a `list` and thus you're trying to access an element when you do something like `list[i]` and `i` cannot be a string, as is the case with `'vars'`.  You probably either need to drop the `['vars']` part or set `messages['english']['merge_vars']` to be a `dict` so that it allows for additional indexing.